# Musixtex Double Drag Tap Drum Rudiment

Tags: musixtex, musixper

It is needed to replicate a Double Drag Tap Drum Rudiment using Musixtex, the current output is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

%Rutinas para Musixtex
\newcommand{\flam}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<  
    \bgroup\sffamily \bfseries\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont #1\egroup
}

\begin{document}
    
  \begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{DoubleDragTap}{\flam{L} \flam{L} R \flam{L} \flam{L} R L \flam{R} \flam{R} L \flam{R} \flam{R} L R}% added for hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-4mm}
      \setlines{1}{0}
      \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule
      \def\snotes{\vnotes0.9\elemskip}
      \startextract
      \A\assignlyrics1{DoubleDragTap}% added to place handindication
      \Notes\charnote f{\Huge{\textcircled{\Large 33}}}\sk\en%$\quad$ lifted the number, \sk is the music way to skip one noteskip
      \snotes\stdstemfalse\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu0a0\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\qb0{a}\tqh0a\en
      \notes\tslur0{a}\ibu0a0\noteskip=1.1\noteskip\qb0{a}\en
      \snotes\stdstemfalse\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu0a0\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\qb0{a}\tqh0a\en
      \notes\tslur0{a}\noteskip=1.7\noteskip\qb0{a}\en
      \notes\tbu0\usf g\qb0a\sk\en
      \snotes\stdstemfalse\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu0a0\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\qb0{a}\tqh0a\en
      \notes\tslur0{a}\ibu0a0\noteskip=1.1\noteskip\qb0{a}\en
      \snotes\stdstemfalse\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu0a0\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\qb0{a}\tqh0a\en
      \notes\tslur0{a}\noteskip=1.7\noteskip\qb0{a}\en
      \notes\tbu0\usf g\qb0a\en
      \zendextract
\end{music}
        
\end{document}
```

current output:
[image: output]

The expected output is as follow:

[image: expected output]

Comment: Again, perhaps you need to move the pitch from a to d? Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lower the pitch from which on you want to start the stem, and you need to start a stem differently numbered from the stem of the main notes, because you do not want to fix the double drag to the main notes.
In my answer I played with various stem lengths (starting from note head M or N).
Instead of inserting manually the DDT, I defined the group, so that you can use just \DDT (see third DDT).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

%Rutinas para Musixtex
\newcommand{\flam}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<  
    \bgroup\sffamily \bfseries\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont #1\egroup
}



  \begin{document}
    
  \begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{DoubleDragTap}{\flam{L} \flam{L} R \flam{L} \flam{L} R L \flam{R} \flam{R} L \flam{R} \flam{R} L R}% added for hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-4mm}%
      \setlines{1}{0}%
      \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule
      \def\snotes{\vnotes0.9\elemskip}%
      \def\DDT{\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu1M0\qb1{a}\tqh1a}% definitiion of the DDT. If you leave out the larger noteskip you get the distance of the first group
      \startextract
      \A\assignlyrics1{DoubleDragTap}% added to place handindication
      \Notes\charnote f{\Huge{\textcircled{\Large 33}}}\sk\en%$\quad$ lifted the number, \sk is the music way to skip one noteskip
      \snotes%\stdstemfalse not necessary, because you need to determine the stem length manually
      {\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu0N0%\noteskip=1.3\noteskip
      \qb0{a}\tqh0a}\en
      \notes
      \tslur0{a}\ibu0a0%\noteskip=1.1\noteskip%
      \qb0{a}\en
      \snotes%\stdstemfalse
      \tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu1M0\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\qb1{a}\tqh1a\en
      \notes\tslur0{a}\noteskip=1.7\noteskip\qb0{a}\en
      \notes\tbu0\usf g\qb0a\sk\en
      %\snotes\stdstemfalse
      \snotes\DDT% defined code inserted
      %\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu0a0\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\qb0{a}\tqh0a
      \en
      \notes\tslur0{a}\ibu0a0\noteskip=1.1\noteskip\qb0{a}\en
      \snotes\stdstemfalse\tinynotesize\islurd0a\ibbu0a0\noteskip=1.3\noteskip\qb0{a}\tqh0a\en
      \notes\tslur0{a}\noteskip=1.7\noteskip\qb0{a}\en
      \notes\tbu0\usf g\qb0a\en
      \zendextract
\end{music}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]